# I need to take an int and convert it into its binary notation (C#)

Tags: c#, binary

I need to take an int and turn it into its byte form.

i.e. I need to take '1' and turn it into '00000001'
or '160' and turn it into '10100000'

Currently, I am using this

```
            int x = 3;
            string s = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
            int b = int.Parse(s);
```

This is an awful way to do things, so I am looking for a better way.

Any Suggestions?

**EDIT**

Basically, I need to get a list of every number up to 256 in base-2.  I'm going to store all the numbers in a list, and keep them in a table on my db.

**UPDATE**

I decided to keep the base-2 number as a string instead of parsing it back.  Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: You've already got its binary value in string s, why do you convert it back to an int?(which "looks" like a binary value but actually it's a larger int value)

Comment: `x` is already the number 160 in byte form. `Convert.ToString(x, 2)` returns that number in binary, just like `Convert.ToString(x)` returns the number in decimal.

Comment: Its a standard way.. if you want to simplify even further, create a extension method for int like "3.to_b(base)" and call the actual converstion inside

Comment: why does it need to be an int at the end? In your code, it contains a number that looks like a binary representation when reading it as a decimal number! I mean, the int already *is* binary... ToString makes it readable as binary...

Comment: @Ramesh Vel: What kind of method name is `to_b`??? You sound like my colleagues!

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, there is nothing wrong with naming a method to_b.. in ruby world every conversion method is defined like this to_s(toString),to_i(int).. i was learning ruby for few weeks. so it just comes (not intentionally), though its not a standard naming convention in C#.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing the data type Integer with its textual representation.

```
int x = 3;
```

is the number three regardless of the representation (binary, decimal, hexadecimal, etc.)
When you parse the binary textual representation of an integer back to integer you are getting a different number. The framework assumes you are parsing the number represented in the decimal base and gives the corresponding integer.
You can try

```
int x = 1600;
string s = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
int b = int.Parse(s);
```

and it will throw an exception because the binary representation of 1600 interpreted as decimal 
 is too big to fit in an integer

Answer (score 4):

If you need the `byte` form you should take a look at the `BitConverter.GetBytes()` method. It does not return a string, but an array of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The int is already a binary number. What exactly are you looking to do with the new integer? What you are doing is setting a base 10 number to a base 2 value. That's kind of confusing and I think you must be trying to do something that should happen a different way.

Comment: Yes, I guess I just explained it incorrectly. I want a base 2 number from its base 10 counter-part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you need at the end ... this may help:

Turn the int into an int array:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
```

Turn the int into a bit array:

```
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new[] {x});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

The code looks a bit clumsy, but that could be improved a bit.

```
int testValue = 160;
System.Collections.BitArray bitarray = new System.Collections.BitArray(new int[] { testValue });
var bitList = new List<bool>();
foreach (bool bit in bitarray)
    bitList.Add(bit);
bitList.Reverse();
var base2 = 0;
foreach (bool bit in bitList)
{
    base2 *= 10; // Shift one step left
    if (bit)
        base2++; // Add 1 last
}

Console.WriteLine(base2);
```